# MVC Is possible use in "create" scaffolded page, a partial view that uses the same model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model

**MVC Is possible use in "create" scaffolded page, a partial view that uses the same model to summarize data already entered into the same table?**

My model :

```
public class tag
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string TagName { get; set; }
  public string Note { get; set; }
 }
```

my Controller :

```
    // GET: Tags/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var tag = db.Tags;
        return View(tag);
    }
```

my view :

```
@model myAssembly.Models.Tag

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Tag</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


      @Html.Partial("_tagDetail", Model)`
```

my partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<myAssembly.Models.Tag>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tag1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Note)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tag1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My problem is that I receive same error. I don't have idea (sorry) for solve this problem! I hope in your help. Thank you.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Create view should have a model of type `myAssembly.Models.Tag`.  In your controller your `Create` action should just return `View();` or `View(new Tag());`

You should create a PartialViewResult in your controller. Something like

```
// GET: Tags/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
} 

// GET: Tags/List
public ActionResult List()
{
    var tag = db.Tags;
    return PartialView("_tagDetail", tag);
}
```

In your Create view where you're calling the partial, change that to Action.

```
@Html.Action("List")
```

Comment: simply perfect! Thank You Luca.